# " StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM " issue while running script. (Firefox browser)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My requirement is

1. Get all data from grid
2. Search specific text, if found
3. Click check box

My code is,

```
   List<WebElement> totalRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolderChild_grdGroupSelection']/tbody/tr"));
System.out.println("Total Size: "+totalRows.size());

for (int count=1;count<totalRows.size()-1;count++){

System.out.println("Loop count: "+count);

   WebElement rowElement = totalRows.get(count);

    System.out.println("WebElement Tag name: "+rowElement.getTagName());
```

}

Unable to get the value from rowElement.

Here posted Logs, HTML source & snapshot for reference. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM
Command duration or timeout: 294 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bce', time: '2014-09-10 16:27:33'
System info: host: 'Saravanan-PC', ip: '192.168.101.22', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Session ID: 6ea5596b-9f0f-477b-9a11-dc534a0197ee
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=firefox, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=35.0.1}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElements(RemoteWebElement.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElementsByTagName(RemoteWebElement.java:264)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByTagName.findElements(By.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElements(RemoteWebElement.java:163)
    at com.aetherpal.scripts.ClientPolicyProfiles.selectCreatedCSPGroupID(ClientPolicyProfiles.java:95)
    at com.aetherpal.scripts.ClientPolicyProfiles.main(ClientPolicyProfiles.java:80)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bce', time: '2014-09-10 16:27:33'
System info: host: 'Saravanan-PC', ip: '192.168.101.22', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at .fxdriver.cache.getElementAt(resource://fxdriver/modules/web-element-cache.js:8325:24)
    at .Utils.getElementAt(file:///C:/Users/SARAVA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous631926879527649788webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:7922:10)
    at .FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementsInternal_(file:///C:/Users/SARAVA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous631926879527649788webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9636:32)
    at .FirefoxDriver.prototype.findChildElements(file:///C:/Users/SARAVA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous631926879527649788webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9657:3)
    at .DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/SARAVA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous631926879527649788webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11612:16)
    at .DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/SARAVA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous631926879527649788webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11617:7)
    at .DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/SARAVA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous631926879527649788webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11559:5)

Grid: 
[image: Grid]

HTML Source:
[image: HTML source]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I tried with JavascriptExecutor.executeScript() method. Its working fine...I don't know whether this approach is correct way or not..

my sample code is,

```
JavascriptExecutor scriptExecute = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement el = (WebElement) scriptExecute.executeScript("var noOfRows =document.querySelectorAll('table[id=ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolderChild_grdGroupSelection]>tbody>tr'); " +
                "for(var i=1;i<noOfRows.length-1;i++){" +
                "return noOfRows[i]; }");
el.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

The checkbox, ID and the GroupName will be inside the `tr`.

Checkbox is the only `input` element inside the `tr`. You can use the following code which will wait for the checkbox of particular GroupName(in your case `ACL all`) to appear and click on it as soon as it is visible.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//table[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolderChild_grdGroupSelection']//td[text()='ACL all']/..//input")));
element.Click();
```

Comment: no luck. Getting timeout exception..could toy elaborate the Xpath string

Answer (score 0):

The webpage might keep changing due to various reasons ie Reloading/Etc which are not very visible , 
Approach 1 :
One approach to this stale element exception is Trying to reduce the time between 'Find element' and 'Do some action on element'

Approach 2 :

Have a Repeated while loop to check the availablity of element until some condition is true , Also make sure to use Implicit/Explicit/Fluent waits , it helps a lot  but never do a thread.sleep .

Comment: I had tried all the waits but no luck....if I do an action on the webelement then there is no action, simply hanged for a long time